# mysql-Remove from table 5 min after insertion

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How can I remove a row from a table 5 minutes after the row has been INSERTED/UPDATED? Can this be done in mysql or with PHP? Im trying to build a schedule for taking breaks at work. It is stack like, first on top can go on break. After you come on top it has 5 minutes to go on break if time runs out he is removed from list and next on the list can go and the timer is reset.

Comment: I would think a cron job would work best.

Comment: I'd be tempted to use a MySQL EVENT running every 5 minutes - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html as long as you have a date/time recorded against the records you want deleting

Comment: A database seems to be a bit overblown for this O_O I would go with j08691s suggestion!

Comment: Is there any way to do that without cron job?, just using mysql or php?

Comment: @user1223865 you can set a cron job to run a PHP script every x minutes, or nightly if you go with the below answer.

Answer (score 2):

instead of deleting a record, you should just insert a record with start and end time columns and never delete it. You can then check the database if there are any active "breaks", or do whatever else you might want to do with the data without needing to delete anything.

Comment: +1 but just to note that you could then delete old data at convenient times if you don't want it to build up.